# Вектор указателей на функцию с++

Tags: c++, функции, vector

Есть вот такой код:

```
vector<void()> a; 
void b() {}
int main()
{
   a.push_back(b);
   return 0;
}
```

И на этапе компиляции он выбивает ошибку:

```
выполняется компиляция ссылки на экземпляр класс шаблон функции "std::vector<void (void),std::allocator<void (void)>>"
```

Но если я меняю объявление вектора на `vector<void(*)()> a;`, то код спокойно компилируется и работает. Объясните пожалуйста, почему так происходит.

Comment: Потому что `void()` — **не** указатель на функцию. В отличие от `void(*)()`.

Comment: 1) `void()` — это функциональный тип. Нельзя создать вектор функций. `void(*)()` — это указательный тип. Можно создать вектор указателей. 2) Если вектор хранит указатели на функцию `vector<void(*)()> a;` и есть функция `void b() {}`, имеющая функциональный тип `void()`, то код `a.push_back(b);` корректен, т.к. есть неявное преобразование из функционального типа в тип указатель на функцию. Т.е. при добавлении функции в вектор происходит неявное преобразование `void()` в `void(*)()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

например так:

```
typedef void (*func)();

void b() {}

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::vector<func> a; 

    a.push_back(b);
    return 0;
}
```

или так:

```
using func = void (*)();

void b() {}

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::vector<func> a; 

    a.push_back(b);
    return 0;
}
```

впрочем можно сразу писать:

```
std::vector<void (*)()> a;
```